# operator NOT does not invert the result of a NULL comparison

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

Please see these two statements:

```
select 'true'  where (1 = NULL) ; 

select 'true' where not (1 = NULL) ;
```

**Both** (!) of them return empty!

So that means that the expressions `(1=NULL)` and `not (1=NULL)` both return false! But how can that be? I thought the operator `NOT(expression)` will invert the result of the expression ?

According to Microsoft: *"Comparing NULL to a non-NULL value always results in FALSE."*

OK, but that would mean that the operator `NOT`must invert the result. But why does it do this not then?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx

EDIT: I posted the wrong article. 
My quote above is from this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175118.aspx

It seems this article has an error, as stated below in the answers and comments.

Comment: You can't use `=` to compare nulls. You need to use `IS NULL`. Any comparison using `=`with NULL yields `NULL` and the opposite of `NULL` is also `NULL`.  It's the same as asking: "Is the color of your spaceship white" or "Is the color of your spaceship not white". You can't answer either of them because you do not have a spaceship

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but then, the Microsoft documentation is wrong.

Comment: The very article that you have linked to states "an operator that has one or two NULL expressions returns UNKNOWN". Thus your `1=NULL` comparison will always return UNKNOWN, not TRUE or FALSE. UNKNOWN inverts to UNKNOWN. Hence you get nothing back in both cases.

Comment: The link you have provided does not contain the quote from your question.

Comment: To clarify - in the link provided by the OP the statement is in fact correct - using the `=` operator with a `null` value on either side will return `UNKNOWN`. but on the [documentation page of the `=` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx) there is this statement: *Comparing NULL to a non-NULL value always results in FALSE.* Clearly a mistake on this page.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, thanks, I was quoting from the *"= (equals)"* article, but I was wrongly posting the link to the *"Comparison operators"* article.

Comment: I think the combination of the current 4 answers will provide an accurate answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, T-SQL implements what is known as [Three-Valued Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic#Application_in_SQL). That means that each logical expression present in T-SQL code can evaluate to `TRUE`, `FALSE` OR `NULL`. Now SQL Server gives you 2 options to handle logical expressions with `NULLs` with the [SET ANSI_NULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) command. The default behaviour of SQL Server (SET ANSI_NULL ON) is that every logical comparison with `NULL` will return `NULL`. So the following expressions

```
NULL = NULL;
1 = NULL;
1 <> NULL;
```

will all evaluate to `NULL`. If for some reason you want the logical expression to return true or false even if they have `NULL` values in them, you have to turn ANSI_NULL OFF but it is not advisable.

*Small edit*: The only case that a logical expression including `NULL` will evaluate to something other than `NULL` is the following:

```
(NULL) OR (TRUE) = TRUE
```

So the following T-SQL code

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
IF ((NULL=NULL) OR (1=1))
   PRINT 'True';
GO
```

will actually print `True`.

Comment: Indeed, the three-valued-logic explains it all. Thanks for writing, I will upvote you as soon as I have the right to do it (need 15 points)

Comment: No problem! Generally the presence and usage of `NULL` is a very debated and interesting topic in relational databases. If you are really into database theory/ and or databases there are some very cool articles about that topic. This is an awesome article for you to get started with: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/

Answer (score 2):

I think you found a mistake in the documentation, but it's not on the page you linked to, but on another page.

The link in the question states:

> When `SET ANSI_NULLS` is `ON`, an operator that has **one or two** `NULL` expressions returns `UNKNOWN`. When `SET ANSI_NULLS` is `OFF`, the same rules apply, except an equals (`=`) operator returns `TRUE` if **both** expressions are `NULL`. For example, `NULL = NULL` returns `TRUE` when `SET ANSI_NULLS` is `OFF`.

So, no matter what is the value you used in `SET ANSI_NULLS`, the statement `1 = null` will result with an `UNKNOWN` value.

However, in the [= (Equals) (Transact-SQL) page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175118.aspx),
the remarks section states:

> Comparing `NULL` to a non-NULL value always results in `FALSE`.

Clearly that's not the case, since `1 = null` does not return `FALSE`, it returns `UNKNOWN`.

Therefor, my conclusion is that is a mistake in the documentation of the `=` operator documentation.

Comment: Yes, as I wrote above, I posted the wrong link. I quoted from the other page, as you said. I've written a feedback to Microsoft, hopefully they will correct it. Thanks for writing, I will upvote you as soon as I have the right to do it (need 15 points)

Comment: I think the correctly quoted documentation is wrong here too. Try the statement "SELECT 'it works!' WHERE 1 != NULL" with SET ANSI_NULLS ON and OFF and verify that with ANSI_NULLS OFF, the WHERE clause evaluates to true (tested myself on version 12 SP3). With ANSI_NULLS ON any WHERE/AND clause with a NULL comparison results in UNKNOWN, which is then interpreted as false. NOT UNKNOWN is still UNKNOWN and thus still false. Use ANSI_NULLS ON and "IS (NOT) NULL" as a_horse_with_no_name already pointed out in his comment on the original question.

Answer (score 2):

See: **[SET ANSI_NULLS (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188048.aspx)**

> Specifies ISO compliant behavior of the Equals (=) and Not Equal To (<>) comparison operators when they are used with null values in SQL Server 2016.
>
> In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

So if you use this and set it to `OFF`, your code will work as desired:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF

select 'true'  where (1 = NULL) ; 

select 'true' where not (1 = NULL) ;
```

But as stated in the document, it will cause errors in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to check or compare value with `NULL`

```
select 'true'  where 1 IS NULL ; 

select 'true' where 1 IS NOT NULL ;
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. Well, I had a expression like `WHERE NOT (x.a = y.b)`. And this didn't work out correctly when `y.b` was NULL instead of having a 'regular' value.

Comment: I suggest you should check like this `WHERE x.a = y.b  AND  y.b IS NOT NULL`

Comment: But that's not the same ;)